# Hibernate is inserting data in the table which it should only read from

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, checkbox, thymeleaf

I have a table **Specializations** with only two columns (`id`, `specializations`). I'm trying to make a form for creating new request. Request contains:

- list of roles (combobox from enum)
- comments
- date
- specializations (checkboxes from lists of specializations).

If I chose role, type in comment and date - it all works (new request is added to table).

But when I'm trying to check on or few specializations, new request is added but specializations checked are copied and added again into the table.

Here are some fragments of my code:

**request.html**

```
<ul>
 <li th:each="s : ${specializations}">
   <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{request.specializations}" th:value="${s.toString()}"/>
        <label th:text="${s}"></label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**specializations variable in my Request.java**

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Specializations.class)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@CollectionTable(name = "request_specializations", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")/*, 
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"request_id", "specializations" })*/)
@Getter @Setter
private List<Specializations> specializations;
```

**GET method in my controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/employee", "/employee/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String employeeRequest(Model model, RequestForm requestForm) {
    model.addAttribute("specializations", requestService.getSpecializationsList());
    return "/employee";
}
```

I've tried everything I know and I could find and I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Please add how the table looks like before adding specialization and after adding specialization so we are clear on what issue you are facing.

Comment: For starters you should use a `@ModelAttribute` next you should retrieve the specializations from the database instead of creating new ones. Write a `PropertyEditor` or `Converter` for that.

Comment: @Chaitanya
For example my table Specializations(id, specializations) contains rows:
(1, java)
(2, php)
(3, hibernate)
And after I check e.g. java in checkboxes in my html I have:
(1, java)
(2, php)
(3, hibernate)
(4, java)